# Python Tornado не могу понять как правильно оформить coroutine в новом стиле (async/await). По новому не работает

Tags: python, асинхронность, tornado, python-3.7

Добрый день господа программисты прошу помощи. Сам что то не могу разобраться. Честно пробовал это сделать, поратил полдня и не получилось.
У меня есть код socket-клиента и он работает так как я хочу, но в нем я использую (from tornado import gen    и    @gen.coroutine). А это не рекомендуется [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html)

> Native coroutines are the recommended form whenever possible. Only use decoratedcoroutines when compatibility with older versions of Python is required.

Вот код моего клиента:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PeriodicCallback
from tornado import gen
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
import time


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, url, timeout):
        self.url = url
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
        self.ws = None
        self.connect()
        PeriodicCallback(self.keep_alive,1000).start()
        #PeriodicCallback(self.keep_alive, 20000, io_loop=self.ioloop).start()
        self.ioloop.start()

    @gen.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        print ("trying to connect")
        try:
            self.ws = yield websocket_connect(self.url)
        except Exception:
            print ("connection error")
        else:
            print ("connected")
            self.run()

    @gen.coroutine
    def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = yield self.ws.read_message()
            if msg is None:
                print ("connection closed")
                self.ws = None
                break
            print("from server: {}".format(msg))

    def keep_alive(self):
        if self.ws is None:
            self.connect()
        else:
            self.ws.write_message("Hello")

def report():
    try:
       if time.time() - report.T > 2:
        report.T = time.time()
        print (round(report.T-report.start_value))
    except AttributeError:
        report.T = time.time()
        report.start_value = time.time()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PeriodicCallback(report,100).start()
    client = Client("ws://localhost:8881", 5)
```

И теперь я захотел модифицировать код клиента согласно новым правилам принятым в Python 3.7.
У меня получилось вот что:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PeriodicCallback
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
import time


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, url, timeout):
        self.url = url
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
        self.ws = None
        self.connect()
        PeriodicCallback(self.keep_alive,1000).start()
        #PeriodicCallback(self.keep_alive, 20000, io_loop=self.ioloop).start()
        self.ioloop.start()


    async def connect(self):
        print ("trying to connect")
        try:
            self.ws = await websocket_connect(self.url)
            return self.ws
        except Exception:
            print ("connection error")
        else:
            print ("connected")
            self.run()

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = await self.ws.read_message()
            if msg is None:
                print ("connection closed")
                self.ws = None
                break
            print("from server: {}".format(msg))

    def keep_alive(self):
        if self.ws is None:
            self.connect()
        else:
            self.ws.write_message("Hello")

def report():
    try:
    if time.time() - report.T > 2:
        report.T = time.time()
        print (round(report.T-report.start_value))
    except AttributeError:
        report.T = time.time()
        report.start_value = time.time()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PeriodicCallback(report,100).start()
    client = Client("ws://localhost:8881", 5)
```

Но, вот, после такой модификации мой код перестал работать. 
И вот что я вижу в консоле.

```
    PS C:\workspace_ilya\polyna> cd 'c:\workspace_ilya\polyna'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\BenisovichIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'c:\Users\BenisovichIS\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '52425' 'C:\workspace_ilya\sandbox\tornado_client_1.py'
C:\workspace_ilya\sandbox\tornado_client_1.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.connect' was never awaited
  self.connect()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\workspace_ilya\sandbox\tornado_client_1.py:43: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.connect' was never awaited
  self.connect()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2
4
6
8
```

Под дебаггером я вижу, что программа в мою ф-цию  connect() вообще не заходит.
Странно почему так происходит.
Ребята объясните мне пожалуйста почему так происходит, если вам не сложно?

Comment: Возле любого вызова корутины явно или неявно должен стоять `await`. Возле `self.connect()` и `self.run()` у вас `await` отсутствует

Comment: @andreymal только в `__init__` `await` не стаботает. нужен такс

Comment: Что за такс? Я не понимаю.... Дайте пример если не сложно

Comment: task, опечатка.. в ответе есть пара способов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск клиента при инициализации - не очень хорошая идея. Эту часть я бы перенес в конец файла.

Выполнение async функции создает объект, который ещё не исполнен, который можно передать разным исполнителям или запустить на главной очереди (тут asyncio_loop, ioloop - это обертка). Выражение create_task ставит выполнение функции на следующую итерацию loop. Потом self.ioloop.start() начинает крутить очередь и корутина выполнится.

Можно попробовать так ( loop.run_until_complete не подойдет так как блокирует):

```
self.ioloop.asyncio_loop.create_task(self.connect())
```

Можно ещё запустить connect через `asyncio.ensure_future(self.connect()).add_done_callback(fu)`, но не уверен что это легально в торнадо.

Посмотрите ещё [IOLoop.add_future()](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_future)

И вызов корутины из корутины должен выполняться через await.

```
await self.run()
```

`await` прерывает выполнение текущей корутины, ставит в очередь новую корутину. Как только она выполнится выполнение текущей возобновится.

Comment: Спасибо, уважаемый. Все получилось благодаря вашему совету.   вот какой получился код, если сому интересно. `def __init__(self, url, timeout):
        .....
        self.ioloop.asyncio_loop.create_task(self.connect())
        PeriodicCallback(self.keep_alive,1000).start()
        self.ioloop.start()`   Да и await перед self.run() тоже помог.

Comment: А в качестве понимания как это работатет.... Зачем нужен self.ioloop.asyncio_loop.create_task()? И почему при стпрой нотации как-то  работало без asynchro_loop  ?

Comment: asynchro_loop тут от того что я плохо знаю торнадо, но и проблема не торнадная. Наверное, Ваш код лучше сделать через handler-ы.